# Error disable responsive on mobile when use twitter boostrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have meta tag value. I want run non-responsive on mobile version

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

When run on android. It's OK
[image: No Bug]

But when run on ios, it never work.
[image: Bug]

This is my demo: [Click Here](http://bkladybird.com/)

Comment: What mobile layout are you trying to accomplish? What is showing up on iOS is what should be showing up, if the Bootstrap responsive classes are working properly. The Android screenshot is what appears to be incorrect. It can be fixed by changing `initial-scale=0` to `initial-scale=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try this :
`<meta name='viewport' content='width=1200'>` or same width depend your width of site.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `initial-scale` to `1.0` instead of `0`.